# Check with a timer every second, if a file exist in a given path

Tags: c#, file, timer

I have a simple console application made with C#, in which I create a zip file. From another console application, I let a timer tick every second to check if the directory where I create the .zip file in the first app contains a .zip file, but it doesn't work.

I implemented the code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    private static String path = "C:\\Path\\*.zip";

    public static void Main()
    {
        SetTimer();

        Console.WriteLine("\nChecking the ZIP file is created on the directory...\n");
        Console.WriteLine("The application started at {0:HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    private static void SetTimer()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            // Create a timer with a two second interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ZIP file created.");
            aTimer.Stop();
            aTimer.Dispose();

            Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
        }     
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss}",
                          e.SignalTime);
    }


}
```

Anyone could help me?
Thanks!

Comment: why are you reinventing the wheel.. use `FileWatcher` also if it's not working why don't you set break points and step through the code.. also at some point you are going to want to enable and disable the timer I would start by putting breakpoints in your code and seeing why things are not happening as expected. `Google` the following `FileSystemWatcher`

Comment: You have all the raison. Now I need to know when I want to stop the timer if there are a zip file

Comment: `FileWatcher` can have undesirable side effects, like preventing a watched USB drive from being formatted... at least it used to have that behavior under Windows XP. I don't know what the OP's motivation is, but occasionally wheels do need reinvention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.Exists` does not support generic wildcard like `*`

Even, [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) is a better way to do this kind of task, here is what you can use immediatly to solve your issue

```
   if (!new DirectoryInfo("c:\\path").EnumerateFiles("*.zip").Any())
    {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, it works the condition perfectly!